# Is there a difference between 'org 0x7c00' and 'mov ax, 07c0h'?

Tags: assembly, x86, intel

I'm working on an operating system that is written in x86 Intel Assembly, and I noticed some guides, like the OS Dev wiki, has `mov ax, 07c0` at the very start in their examples. Then, from my research on writing an operating system, I've found, for example, YouTube videos on this subject that put `org 0x7C00` at the beginning of the boot loader file.

My question is: Is there any difference between the two? And if their is, which is the better choice, and what exactly are the differences?

Comment: These two lines do completely different things.  One is a directive, the other one is an instruction.  That's not even close.  Perhaps you might want to learn some 8086 assembly in general before attempting to write a boot loader.

Comment: Actually, I know Assembly really well, and I've only written a simple boot loader from what I've learned _so far._ Learning assembly isn't my problem - my problem is mixed sources, if that makes sense. Researching the topic of boot loaders and operating systems, brings a whole bunch of different sources. Some sources do the directive, without the  instruction. And some do the exact opposite, and some even do both or none, and some how the writer say's it works.

Comment: Do you know what the `org 0x7c00` directive does?  Have you read [how the BIOS loads your boot loader](https://wiki.osdev.org/MBR#MBR_Bootstrap)? Then it should be clear why `org 0x7c00` is usually used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there any difference between the[se] two?

To understand the difference between those two, you have to understand the `segment:offset` model of 8086 assembly:

*In REAL mode* a segment value denotes a value 16(dec)=10(hex) times the value of an offset value.

So a value of segment `0000` and offset `0x7c00` denotes the same position in memory as segment `07C0` and offset `0000` = 07C0h * 10h = 7C00h. See [here at OSDev:RealMode](https://wiki.osdev.org/Real_Mode) for an extended explanation.

So overall `0000:7C00` is the same as `07C0:0000`.

With the `ORG` directive you do set the beginning of a (memory) section.

> Is there any difference between the two?

Yes. The difference between these two is the setup of the segment registers and the address registers. If you set the segment registers in a specific way, you'd have to set the address/offset registers in a related way.

> And if their is, which is the better choice, and what exactly are the differences?

There is no "better" choice. It's just a design decision which is merely relevant until you enter *Protected Mode* and set up your *GDT*.

Comment: Alright, I understand this now. I've seen a lot of sources on this subject use the directive and not the instruction; then some do the opposite, and some both or none at all, and they somehow work, according to them. Thank you for clearing that confusion!

Comment: @johnsmithy :That's because a lot of code on the internet with bootloaders is done improperly. If using NASM I'd stick with an explicit `org 0x7c00` and then at the very least set _DS_ to 0x0000. If you use `org 0x0000` (same as nothing at all) you should be setting _DS_ to 0x07C0. If you are reading disk sectors into memory you really should also set _SS:SP_ to some place you know you won't be clobbering (Set SS to 0x0000 and SP to 0x7c00) places the stack below the bootloader which is a reasonable temporary place for many bootloaders. Any place you know won't interfere with your code will do